# Wordpress Taxonomy does not display post by year

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I was wondering if someone can help me with a fix to my problem. I have the following website: www.fsonline.ro and when I click on "2018" (for example) taxonomy, it will display only the tv series from 2018, not movies (post type) as well. The weird thing is that they are being displayed in the dashboard, but not on the website. 
[Picture from dashboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UYxt.png)
I tried to make it public using the option in the taxonomy file, but without any luck.

```
'public' => true,
```

This is the code that I have in taxonomy.php

```
register_taxonomy 
    ( get_option('year'), 'post', array(
    /* ============================================= */
    'hierarchical' => false,  'label' => __( 'Year', 'mundothemes' ),
    'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true)
    );
```

And this is what I have in functions.php

```
<div class="filtro_y">
<h3><?php _e('Release year','mundothemes'); ?> <span class="icon-sort"></span></h3>
<ul class="scrolling">
<?php $args = array('order' => DESC ,'number' => 50); $camel = get_option('year'); $tax_terms = get_terms($camel,$args);  ?>
<?php foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) { echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '">' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>'; } ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: tv series is a post type?

Comment: @developerme Thanks for your reply. TV Series is a tvshows post type. But the one that is not showing (the movies) is a post type.

Comment: Please read this post, It may be helpful for you

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66219/list-all-posts-in-custom-post-type-by-taxonomy

Comment: Thanks, @GufranHasan. But it didn't really help me. =/